# Best way to list server:database in documentation?

Tags: sql-server

Not sure how to word this, but I need to list database servers and databases in documentation and emails, alerts etc.

Is there a "preferred" way to do this?

```
SQL-SVR:MyDatabase
SQL-SVR/MyDatabase
SQL-SVR/Instance - MyDatabase
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a "standard" way of listing servers and databases but you can adopt the same convention as in 3-part name (or 4-part if you include linked server name) used in SQL Server which means a dot as the separator:

```
SQL-SERVER.MyDatabase
SQL-SERVER\Instance.MyDatabase
```

Comment: I like the second one :)